# How to get values from four joined tables to the view in EF

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core

My Question is how to get columns data from the last table like *countryid* *countryname*
I want to show this values in views page

controller

```
var dt = db.Types.Where(x => x.TypeId == id).FirstOrDefault();
            var item = dt;

            var di = db.Items.Where(x => x.TypeId == item.TypeId).ToList();
            foreach (var item1 in di)
            {
                var dic = db.ItemsCountries.Where(x => x.ItemId == item1.ItemId).ToList();
                foreach (var ee in dic)
                {
                    var eee = db.Entities.Where(x => x.EntityId == ee.EntityId).ToList();
                    foreach (var c in eee)
                    {
                        var country = db.Countries.Where(x => x.CountryId == c.CountryId).Distinct().ToList();

                        var projects = country.GroupBy(x => x.CountryId)
                            .Select(group => new { group.Key, l = group.ToList() }).ToList().Take(10);

                        

                        return View(projects);

                    }

                }

}

            }
```

Model:

```
@model IEnumerable<website.Models.types>


@{ ViewData["Title"] = "ProjectsView";}
```

In the view i can't get the fourth table columns in the intellisense
I don't know what i did wrong.

```
                    @if (Model != null)
                    {
                @foreach (var item in Model)
                {


                <ul class="country">
                    <li><a href=""></a>@item.</li>


                </ul>} }
```

Comment: Please check the post code, in the controller action method, it will return a new list object, instead of the type model. Besides, the return command is inside the foreach statement, please make sure you are not posting the wrong code?

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> var dt = db.Types.Where(x => x.TypeId == id).FirstOrDefault();
>             var item = dt;
>
>             var di = db.Items.Where(x => x.TypeId == item.TypeId).ToList();
>             foreach (var item1 in di)
>             {
>                 var dic = db.ItemsCountries.Where(x => x.ItemId == item1.ItemId).ToList();
>                 foreach (var ee in dic)
>                 {
>                     var eee = db.Entities.Where(x => x.EntityId == ee.EntityId).ToList();
>                     foreach (var c in eee)
>                     {
>                         var country = db.Countries.Where(x => x.CountryId == c.CountryId).Distinct().ToList();
>
>                         var projects = country.GroupBy(x => x.CountryId)
>                             .Select(group => new { group.Key, l = group.ToList() }).ToList().Take(10);
>  
>                         return View(projects);
>
>                     } 
>                 }
>              }
>             }
> ```

Perhaps the issue is that you didn't assign the object name in the Linq select statement.

Please check the above code, since the `return View(projects);` located in the foreach statement, in the first time loop, it will return the View and exits the loop through.

If want to use this method to display the data, try to modify your code like this (add Object name in the select statement):

types class (assume it contains the following properties):

```
public class types
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public int CountryId { get; set; }
    public string CountryName { get; set; } 
}
```

Modify the following code:

```
  var projects = country.GroupBy(x => x.CountryId)
                            .Select(group => new { group.Key, l = group.ToList() }).ToList().Take(10);
   return View(projects);
```

to:

```
  var projects = country.GroupBy(x => x.CountryId)
                            .Select(group => new types{ CountryId = group.Key, CountryName  = group.ToList().FirstOrDefault().CountryName }).ToList().Take(10);

  return View(projects);
```

In my opinion, I guess you want to show all of the country information. If that is the case, you could define a List object outside the Foreach statement (such as typeslist), then, in the Foreach statement, after looping through the type, you could insert the selected country in the list, finally you could return the countryList to the View.

sample code like this:

```
        var dt = db.Types.Where(x => x.TypeId == id).FirstOrDefault();
        var item = dt;

        //define a list to store the select types
        List<types> typesList = new List<types>();
        var di = db.Items.Where(x => x.TypeId == item.TypeId).ToList();
        foreach (var item1 in di)
        {
            var dic = db.ItemsCountries.Where(x => x.ItemId == item1.ItemId).ToList();
            foreach (var ee in dic)
            {
                var eee = db.Entities.Where(x => x.EntityId == ee.EntityId).ToList();
                foreach (var c in eee)
                {
                    var country = db.Countries.Where(x => x.CountryId == c.CountryId).Distinct().ToList();

                    List<types> projects = country.GroupBy(x => x.CountryId)
                        .Select(group => new types{ CountryId = group.Key, CountryName = group.ToList().FirstOrDefault().CountryName }).ToList().Take(10);

                    //insert the selected items into the typeslist
                    typesList.AddRange(projects);
                    //return View(projects);
                } 
            } 
        }
        // return the typeslist to the view.
        return View(typesList);
```

Then, in the View page, you could use the following code to display the data.

```
@model IEnumerable<MVCSample.Models.types>

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Default";
}
              
@if (Model != null)
{
    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {


        <ul class="country">
            <li><a href=""></a>@item.CountryId @item.CountryName </li>


        </ul>}}
```

The output like this:

[image]